# Alignment of submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am unable to get rid of a gap between my nav bar and my submenu dropdown menu. You can view the issue [here](http://martha-nutritionist.com/new/).

My css is here:

```
nav#nav{
    float: left;
    font: 14px/16px 'MuseoSlab500Regular', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 99999;
    /*background-image: url(../images/2blkbg.png);*/
    /*background-repeat: repeat-x;*/
    padding-left: 30px;
    /*background-position: left bottom;*/
    background-color: #000;
    height: 53px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
#nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 49px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#nav ul a,#nav li.current-menu-ancestor a{
    display: block;
    height:83px;
    line-height: 53px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #fff;
}
#nav ul .current_page_item a, #nav ul .current-menu-item  a, #nav ul > .current-menu-parent a{
    color:#a0ce4e;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-color:#a0ce4e;
}
#nav ul li{
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 170px;
    background: #edebeb;
    z-index: 100000;
    border-top: 3px solid #a0ce4e;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul li{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/blkbg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wrapper #nav ul li ul li a{
    background: url(../images/subnav_sep.jpg) repeat-x bottom left;
    border: 0;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: 20px;
    font: 13px/30px 'PTSansRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333333 !important;
}
#wrapper #nav ul li ul li a:hover,#wrapper #nav ul li ul li.current-menu-item a{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
#nav ul ul ul{
    display:none !important;
}
#nav ul ul li:hover ul{
    display:block !important;
    top:-3px;left:170px;
}
#nav select{
    max-width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav > li > a,#nav li.current-menu-ancestor a {
  height:83px;
  line-height:83px;
}
#nav ul ul {
  top:86px;
}
```

Set the `top` and that will remove the excess of gap:

```
#nav ul ul {
  top:86px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good you posted the url, since problem is not in the css you included. The problem is in this class:

```
#nav ul ul {
  top:86px;
}
```

This top-offset should be set to **53px**, the same height as your menu bar (`nav#nav`):

```
#nav ul ul {
  top:53px;
}
```

This css-class actually is *not* in your css-stylesheet, but in your page itself. It is included in the `<head></head>`.